# How to execute karate-Gatling performance test scripts in windows and linux server?

Tags: karate

Recently I learnt how to use standalone Karate JAR file to execute feature files.
I have some Karate-Gatling performance test scripts as well and want to run this in Windows/Linux server.
In local, I use the cmd - "mvn clean test-compile gatling:test" to execute the karate-gatling test scripts.
Can we run performance test scripts using standalone Karate JAR file? If yes, please share the command? If not, pls explain how to execute the performance test scripts in server?

Thanks,
Sudha

Answer (score 0):

No the stand-alone JAR does not support Gatling. It may be technically possible, but this is something we hope the community (or maybe you) can do some research and contribute.

So you need a Maven or Gradle project. It should be simple to port your existing scripts to the shape needed. Not sure if this helps - but you should be able to create a single "fat jar" via the Maven-Shade plugin that you can take and run wherever, but again - it needs some investigation.